Elasticsarch - How Do You Build A Search Query For An Object With Two Keys?
I have an Elasticsearch index with an array of items that looks like:
[{
  ...,
  "_source": {
    "id": ....
    "name": "apples",
    "organization_size": {
      "start": 0
      "end": 99 
    } 
  }    
}, {
  ...,
  "_source": {
    "id": ....
    "name": "bananas",
    "organization_size": {
      "start": 100
      "end": 499
    } 
  }    
}]

I am getting the following URL params from the front-end client:
filters[organization_size][][key][start]: 0
filters[organization_size][][key][end]: 99

What's the proper way of building out an Elasticsearch query string here so that the above request returns the "apples" result?
I am using Ruby on Rails, but the ES query buildout can be agnostic.

can you provide the mapping of the field organization_size

It's what @LeDevNovice wrote down in his answer

To build an Elasticsearch query that matches documents based on the provided organization size range from the front-end client, you have to ensure that your organization_size field is properly mapped in your index mapping. The start and end fields of the organization_field should be of an integer type.
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "organization_size": {
        "properties": {
          "start": { "type": "integer" },
          "end": { "type": "integer" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And then you will be able to define a multi terms query to be able to return apples if the two matches.
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "organization_size.start": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "organization_size.end": 99
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Note that you can’t change the type of an existing field in the mapping. You would need to create a new index with the correct mapping and reindex your data if necessary.

I already have the mapping and it matches what you wrote down in the above.  For the query you wrote, you're looking for anything between 0 and 99.  In my scenario, the 0 and 99 are just keys, the front-end will always pass to the back-end the start and end keys.  These keys will match exactly what's saved in the index (the index also saves this property with a start and end key).  So I am not looking for a greater than 0 and less than 99 range, but rather something that matches the start and end keys.

Sorry for the misunderstanding of your problem. I I understand clearly, the front-end will always pass the start and end keys that exactly match what is saved in the index, so here for example 0 and 99. If so, you should use a term query that needs to match the two exact values rather than a range query. It ensures that only documents with the exact start and end values provided will be returned, which includes the "apples" document in this case.
I have changed my answer to show you the new query.

How would you build a multiple or statement here?  So if I have two ranges, (ie. 0-99, then 100 through 499), I would like ES to return records that match either

I think the good practice here would be to search if the question already exists and if not create another question for this purpose :)
